# image of a piecewise function

Tags: functions

I am given the piecewise function $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z},$ $ f(x) =\left\{ \begin{matrix}
      2n, & \text{if }n \text{ is even} \\
      n, & \text{if }n \text{ is odd}  
    \end{matrix}\right.$

I need to find the image of this function. So far I have tried plotting out a list of points, but I am unable to find a pattern. Is there a better approach to this problem?

Comment: You have a piecewise function, so begin by focusing only on one piece at a time. For instance, what's the image of $f$ under the set of odd integers?

Comment: So $\text{im}(f)$ contains all odd integers, as well as all integer multiples of 4. But how do I express that as one set? Do I just say $\{n \mid n $ is odd, or $ n=4t, t \in \mathbb{Z} \}$?

Comment: Exactly @jeanquilt.